# Do I need a transit visa for a stopover in Dubai for less than 8 hours en route to Australia?

Tags: visas, transit, dubai, uae, dxb

I am flying on Emirates from South Africa via Dubai to Australia and my stop-over is about six hours before I fly to Perth. Do I need a visa? I am South African.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: If you're not planning on leaving the airport and there are less than 12 hrs between your flights, you don't need a visa. http://www.uae-embassy.ae/Embassies/uk/Content/591

Comment: stopover usually is above 12h and it (depends on international and domestic flight). Below 12 is considered transit.